# Can I save an hard copy version of my iCloud Photo Library on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

I want to unsubscribe from iCloud and, this way, I'll lose all the photos that I previously uploaded on the iCloud Library. Is there a way to unsubscribe from iCloud and keep a hard copy high-resolution version of the photos on my iPhone gallery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before turning off iCloud Photos, you can make Photos download the originals. You'll need enough space on your iPhone first though.

> To download the original photos and videos on your iOS device, go to Settings > [your name] > iCloud > Photos and select Download and Keep Originals

[Get help with iCloud Photos - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204570)